# I wrote a function that takes one string and, capitalize the last character of each word in uppercase and the rest in lowercase.What's wrong with it?

Tags: c, char, c-strings, case-sensitive, function-definition

I have a function that takes one string and, capitalize the last character
of each word in uppercase and the rest in lowercase.
If a word has a single letter, it must be capitalized.

My code:

```
#include <string.h>
char* rcapitalize(char* p)
{
    char space = 32,tab = 9;
    int len = strlen(p);
    for (int i = 0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if (p[i]>='a' && p[i]<='z' && (p[i+1])==space ||p[i]>='a' && p[i]<='z' && (p[i+1])=='\0' ||p[i]>='a' && p[i]<='z' && (p[i+1])==tab)
        {
            p[i]=p[i]-32;
        }
        else if (p[i]>='A' && p[i]<='Z' && (p[i+1])!=tab ||p[i]>='A' && p[i]<='Z' && (p[i+1])!=space || p[i]>='A' && p[i]<='Z' && (p[i+1])!='\0')
        {
            p[i] = p[i]+32;
        }
        
        
    }
    return p;
}
```

> ```
> Input: "a FiRSt LiTTlE TESt"
> Return Value: "A firsT littlE tesT"
> My return value: "A firsT little tesT"
> ```

Why it's lowercasing the `'E'` in a word `"littlE"`?

Comment: `man isspace`, `man isdigit`, `man isalnum`, etc

Comment: Your long Boolean expressions are hard to follow.  I would suggest breaking them up, perhaps with nested `if`s.  I suspect you have your tests grouped wrong and need some parentheses, but again, it's so hard to read that it's not clear.  @WilliamPursell's suggestion of using the ctype macros will also simplify things greatly; in addition to those, you probably also want `isupper, islower, toupper, tolower`.

Comment: The only classification you need is `isspace()`. Step 1, lowercase the whole string. Step 2, uppercase the last letter of each word. Function `toupper()` won't uppercase any non-alpha character, you can trust it. When that works, you could combine the two steps.

Comment: @WeatherVane `tolower` also will not harm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `"LiTTlE"` is the only word in the string that contains the last letter in the upper case.

The first sub-expression of the else if statement

```
p[i]>='A' && p[i]<='Z' && (p[i+1])!=tab
```

will always evaluate to true because the character `p[i+1]` is indeed unequal to `tab`. So the full expression will also always evaluate to true.

Instead of the logical OR operator you have to use the logical AND operator in the full expression of this else if statement.

For example it could look like

```
else if ( p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] <= 'Z' && p[i+1] != tab && p[i+1] != space && p[i+1] != '\0' )
```

Nevertheless the program looks bad. It will not work correctly for example if instead of the ASDII character table there will be used the EBCDIC character table.

For starters do not use magic numbers like `32`.
The used logical expressions are too compound.
The call of `strlen` is redundant.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * rcapitalize( char *s )
{
    for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
        unsigned char c1 = p[0], c2 = p[1];
        
        if ( isalpha( c1 ) )
        {
            if ( isspace( c2 ) || c2 == '\0' )
            {
                *p = toupper( c1 );
            }
            else if ( isupper( c1 ) )
            {
                *p = tolower( c1 );
            }
        }
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "a FiRSt LiTTlE TESt";
    
    puts( rcapitalize( s ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A firsT littlE tesT
```

Answer (score 2):

This function has a few bugs

But this is the condition directly causing the error that's lowercase-ing that 'E'.

This is supposed to match capital letters not at the end of a word right? But instead it matches all capital letters.

```
else if (p[i]>='A' && p[i]<='Z' && (p[i+1])!=tab ||p[i]>='A' && p[i]<='Z' && (p[i+1])!=space || p[i]>='A' && p[i]<='Z' && (p[i+1])!='\0'
```

When execution gets to the condition that fails `p[i] == 'E'`, then `(p[i+1])!='\0'` is true (even though `(p[i+1])!=space` is false)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comment:

- your if conditions are overly complicated, you should try to factorize them
- for your tests, you should use C standard functions like isspace()
- for your processing, you should use C standard functions like toupper()

By simplifying your if conditions, you would see that `(p[i+1]) != tab || (p[i+1]) != space` is always true.

According to all this, here is a simplified version of your function:

```
char* rcapitalize(char* p) {
    size_t len = strlen(p);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (p[i + 1] == '\0' || isspace(p[i + 1])) {
            p[i] = toupper(p[i]);
        } else {
            p[i] = tolower(p[i]);
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

Comment: @P__J__ Thanks, fixed.

Comment: there is  need of `strlen` as well. Now you need to traverse string twice without the need

Comment: Right. That's not my code and I try to stick to OP's proposal as much as possible. OP is a beginner. I only meant to simplify, not optimize. Your answer is optimized, you should explain why inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition doesn't do what you want.

Your checks on characters is "valid" because it's ASCII but the thorough version would consist in using the function is_lower, is_upper, toupper, tolower, pointers as the other answer shows

but I think this is a learning exercice for beginner so it's okay to use ASCII

```
char* rcapitalize(char *p) {
  char space = 32, tab = 9;
  int len = strlen(p);

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (i + 1 <= len && (p[i + 1] == space || p[i + 1] == tab || p[i + 1] == '\0')) {
      if (p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] <= 'Z')
        p[i] += 32;
      if (p[i] >= 'a' && p[i] <= 'z')
        p[i] -= 32;
    }
  }
  return p;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be simplified  by using functions to do some common stuff (ASCII only):

```
int myisspace(int c)
{
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\t') return 1;
    return 0;
}

int myisupperletter(int c)
{
    if((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int myislowerletter(int c)
{
    if((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')) return 1;
    return 0;
}


int mytolower(int c)
{
    if(myisupperletter(c)) c += 'a' - 'A';
    return c;
}

int mytoupper(int c)
{
    if(myislowerletter(c)) c -= 'a' - 'A';
    return c;
}


char* rcapitalize(char* p)
{
    
    for(char *wrk = p; *wrk; wrk++)
    {
        if(myisspace(wrk[1]) || !wrk[1]) *wrk = mytoupper(*wrk);
        else *wrk = mytolower(*wrk);
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    char r[] = "  aa      -----  FiRSt LiTTlE TESt   ";
    printf("%s\n", rcapitalize(r));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ssnMPY

or you can use functions from standard library

```
char* rcapitalize(char* p)
{
    for(char *wrk = p; *wrk; wrk++)
    {
        if(isspace(wrk[1]) || !wrk[1]) *wrk = toupper(*wrk);
        else *wrk = tolower(*wrk);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Usage

```
int main()
{
    char r[] = "  aa        FiRSt LiTTlE TESt   ";
    printf("%s\n", rcapitalize(r));
}
```

And here you can test and play yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/a4xr4G

Comment: Sometimes it is simpler to convert all char to the desired case without inquiring about the case.  Of course, cache reads are faster than RAM writes!

It might be less logic to process the char[] in reverse, setting a case lower flag after capitalizing the first seen (last) letter.  However, you need to look out for boundaries either way: the null char at the end or the beginning of line as well as isspace().

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett `for` checks  for the null terminator. Code checks everything corectly. Setting everything lowercase and traversing again is very inefficent. I think you did not read the code catefully

Comment: Not saying it does not, just commenting on the pros and cons of various approaches.